# Generation android app with ionic?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/a-simple-weather-forecast-app-with-ionic-framework-and-forecastio/107) to get started with Ionic Framework. I'm stuck in this part:

```
ionic platform add ios
```

when i execute it, Terminal shows me this error:

[image: terminal error]

noting that hen i run `echo $ANDROID_HOME` it shows me `/opt/android-sdk`, the same thing when i execute `sudo android` it shows me SDK manager.
I have re-installed Android SDK, NODE, Ionic etc using the script on [this page](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/09/install-android-cordova-ionic-framework-ubuntu/) but i always get the same result.
What should i do?

PS: i'm running Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: What happens when you try to add the android platform without sudo?

Comment: i get the same error in addition to this on top:
addCliHookDirectory fs.chmodSync: Error: EPERM, operation not permitted 'hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js'

Comment: Did you use sudo to create your ionic project?  If you did, try to create a new project and use no sudo.  Sudo should not be used with Ionic commands.  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: i get this when i run ionic without sudo
http://f.cl.ly/items/040W203f163g1l2y1c14/screenshot.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution was the following, after executing the shell script fire up the SDK Manager and install this `Android 4.4.2 API19` then run ionic CLI commands without `sudo` and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

set your path manually in `.bash_profile`.

```
export PATH=${PATH}:<your_android_sdk_location>/platform-tools
export PATH=${PATH}:<your_android_sdk_location>/tools
```